# animationdrawable

Tags: android-layout

> I get error on this code from runtime-

```
ImageView couponImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.couponImg);
    couponImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.coupon);

    AnimationDrawable couponAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)    
couponImage.getBackground();
    couponAnimation.start();
```

> the "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable" >error.
>   But if I do not use "AnimationDrawable couponAnimation " eclipse complains.

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageView couponImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.couponImg);

AnimationDrawable couponImg = 
           (AnimationDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.couponImg);

couponImg.setBackgroundDrawable(couponImg);

couponImg.start();
```